# Why won't contact ID display in a profile?

Tags: profile

I want to display Contact ID as a View only field in a profile. I can add the field to the profile. Other View only fields display properly for a logged in user when they visit the relevant contribution page but the Contact ID field is blank. (The profile displays their name, address and phone number. Phone number is the only field they can edit.  They need to make all other changes by editing their Drupal user record.)

I believe I have tried all combinations of **Drupal user account registration option?** and **What to do upon duplicate match** under the Advanced Settings for the profile in case a specific combination was required.

The contact ID does show up in the email receipt, which is the most important part I suppose as the receipt is cc'd to someone who needs that contact ID.  However the "empty" Contact Id field on the contribution form will confuse the users.

Does anyone know if/how I can get the Contact ID value to display properly?

(Note: This non-appearance of the contact ID happens on our 4.4.20 installation and also on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. I have only been able to check the contents of the email receipt on our installation.)

Comment: May not be applicable, but the other approach is to get the token for the contact_id in to the System Template if you are mostly wanting to do this so you get the Contact ID in to the receipt.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is not available in core civicrm, for Drupal users you can have the contact_id displayed in a Webform : just change the Widget to "Textfield" (in the WEBFORM tab) to make it visible

Comment: This answer applies to Webform-CiviCRM integration; however, it seems that a native CiviCRM profile is in use here.

Comment: I agree, but since JoAnne uses Drupal, CiviCRM Webform Integration may bring an easy soluton.